# Select database subset if requirement is met on main database

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the title value of all employes with first_name Georgi and last_name Facello with this input:

```
SELECT employees.emp_no, title
from employees,
     employees.titles
where first_name = 'Georgi'
  and last_name = 'Facello';
```

Employees database:

```
# emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date
'10001', '1953-09-02', 'Georgi', 'Facello', 'M', '1986-06-26'
'10002', '1964-06-02', 'Bezalel', 'Simmel', 'F', '1985-11-21'
```

Employees.titles:

```
# emp_no, title, from_date, to_date
'10001', 'Senior Engineer', '1986-06-26', '9999-01-01'
'10002', 'Staff', '1996-08-03', '9999-01-01'
```

But this input gives the following output:

```
# emp_no, title
'10001', 'Senior Engineer'
'55649', 'Senior Engineer'
'10001', 'Staff'
'55649', 'Staff'
'10001', 'Senior Engineer'
'55649', 'Senior Engineer'
```

This output goes up to 999+ which is obviously not correct, any ideas how to get the correct output?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit  `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `JOIN` instead of doining `CROSS JOIN` :

```
SELECT es.emp_no, t.title
FROM employees es INNER JOIN
     employees.titles t
     ON t.emp_no = es.emp_no
WHERE es.first_name = 'Georgi' AND es.last_name = 'Facello';
```

Use always proper explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of using commas in `FROM` clause